# QueryBuilder - IN expression

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine, query-builder

I've created a quiz and I record in DB if people answered right to all question and the time they take to finish the quiz.

I'm trying to create a querybuilder to retrieve the guy who answered correct to the maximum of questions with the minimum of time.

My table looks like this :
[image]

So, the request (which works) I did in SQL in the DB is :

```
SELECT 
  id
FROM
  public.user_quizz
WHERE 
  quizz_id = 4
  AND 
    number_correct_answers IN (SELECT max(number_correct_answers) FROM user_quizz WHERE quizz_id = 4)
  AND 
    answered_in IN (SELECT min(answered_in) FROM user_quizz WHERE quizz_id = 4);
```

Of course, I don't know if it's the best (and the most optimal) request we could do in this case, but it works.

Now, I'm trying to translate this query into querybuilder.

I'm blocked on the **IN** expression. I don't know how I could do the SELECT here.

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');

        $query = $qb->select('u')
            ->andWhere(
                $qb->expr()->eq('u.quizz', ':quizzId'),
                $qb->expr()->in(
                    'u.numberCorrectAnswers',

                )
            )
            ->setParameter('quizzId', $quizz->getId())
            ->getQuery()
        ;
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why don't you simple make a [native query](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/native-sql.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$qbSelectMax = $this->createQueryBuilder('uc')  // user copy, to prevent alias collisions
$qbSelectMax
   ->select($qb->expr()->max('uc.numberCorrectAnswers'))
   ->where($qb->expr()->eq('uc.quizz', ':quizzId'));      

$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
$query = $qb->select('u')
    ->andWhere(
        $qb->expr()->eq('u.quizz', ':quizzId'),
        $qb->expr()->in(
            'u.numberCorrectAnswers',
            $qbSelectMax->getDQL()
        )
    )
    ->setParameter('quizzId', $quizz->getId())
    ->getQuery();
```

You can create sub DQL query to select max `numberCorrectAnswers` first and then pass DQL right into `in` parameter

Comment: Create sub DQL query worked perfectly ! But I don't retrieve the object at the end. When I use $qb->select('u'), my PC bug, like it was an infinite loop and then I have to restart the PC. But when I'm selecting $qb->select('u.id') it works. That's strange

Comment: @Alexis what you do next with QB? It seems like you tried to dump the query result or something

Comment: Yes indeed, I try to dump the query ( $query->getDQL() ) and the result ( $query->getResult() ). I shouldn't ?

Comment: well yeah, `var_dump($query->getResult());` will result in tons of data, with all related entities and relations, even if you have not so much data in database. You have to serialize data and return it as a regular response

Comment: @Alexis Here is what you are probably looking for https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html, it is how you can specify which properties you want to extract from DQL selection

Answer (score 0):

`ORDER BY` could be used to sort by number of answers and less time taken:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
   ->orderBy('u.numberCorrectAnswers', 'DESC')
   ->addOrderBy('u.answeredIn', 'ASC');
```